# When did it become allowed to walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the Johor–Singapore Causeway?

Tags: borders, singapore, malaysia, walking

My research so far:

1. This [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/38564/1810) by [lambshaanxy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/lambshaanxy) states it was not possible in 2014:

> you can't even walk across the Causeway now that Malaysia shifted to its new ridiculously huge and rather distant Customs building.

2. The [Wikipedia page on the Johor–Singapore Causeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johor%E2%80%93Singapore_Causeway) states:

> Since 26 March 2022, both countries have permitted pedestrians to walk along the Causeway by foot

3. However, this [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/ZXrelv2UiBs?si=NvZRT4_3xHn2v4uI) shows it was already allowed in 2018 (screenshots in case the video goes down: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6vAw.jpg; https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxRIO.jpg)

This makes me wonder: When did it become allowed to walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the Johor–Singapore Causeway?

Comment: It’s not clear to me what tangible travel problem could be resolved by an answer to this question.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk questions about travel history are on-topic, e.g. [How did Malmö and Copenhagen connect before the Öresund Bridge?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/132739/1810)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, with this kind of questions you almost ask for close votes. It may be travel history but of such a narrow field of interest that most people will not accept it as valuable for the site.

Comment: @Willeke The Johor–Singapore Causeway is one of the busiest border crossings in the world, with 350,000 travellers daily. (quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johor%E2%80%93Singapore_Causeway))

Comment: Related: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4787/58919

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering mostly because I'm unhappy about being quoted out of context --

**It has always been allowed**, as far as I can tell since the day it opened in 1924, although passage across has been interrupted several times by wars, epidemics, etc.

Originally, the Causeway used to have a "proper" pedestrian sidewalk all the way across as well.  But in 2008 Malaysia opened a [new, hugely expanded Customs, Immigration and Quarantine complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_Iskandar_Building) located several km further away from the border, which did not have any provisions for pedestrians, and IIRC they even announced that pedestrians would not longer be allowed at some point.  However, as far as I know this wasn't ever really enforced, and since the border remained congested as ever it remained a useful safety valve.  It's a long, unpleasant and dangerous walk though, so my "can't really walk across" was referring to this being *impractical* especially if you have luggage etc, not legally banned.

During COVID, from early 2020 to 2022, the Causeway was closed to *all* travellers, vehicular or pedestrian, except a thin trickle of people with permits that were shuttled back and forth on special buses.  With the lifting of COVID measures pedestrian access became possible again, and this is what the "since March 2022" references are talking about.

Comment: Thanks, my apologies I didn't intend to misquote you . You're welcome to edit my question. Is the crossing by foot really that impractical? https://youtu.be/ZXrelv2UiBs?si=SQJ50xrbaRFhTeg3 says it takes 15 minutes and we see many pedestrians in their video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6vAw.jpg ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxRIO.jpg

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It was a hot, sweaty and exhaust-laden hike even back pre-2008 when the walk was under 1 km and you had a sidewalk all the way.  But the car/bus queues on holidays etc can be *really* bad (multiple hours), so it may still be the lesser of two evils.